# Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

Tags: java, android-studio

Error not resolving

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven', version: '1.4']
        > Failed to apply plugin 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'.
           > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.
              > Could not generate a decorated class for type AndroidMavenPlugin.
                 > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/MavenPomMetaInfoProvider
```

Gradle version 7.0.2

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
    id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "2.1"
}
```

Comment: share your app level and project level gradle file

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem?